# Adding data to a reference to change the referenced array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I have built a function to retrieve the last specified key of an array, it references the array and displays it fine, however, when I try to add to the reference variable, it does not affect the referenced array.

Here is my code:

```
class test {
    public function __construct() {
        // For testing
        $this->keys[] = 'key1';
        $this->keys[] = 'key2';
        $this->array['key1']['key2'] = 'Hello World';
    }
    protected function &getArray() {
        $array = &$this->array;
        foreach($this->keys as $key) {
            $array = &$array[$key];
        }
        return $array;
    }
    function add() {
        $tmpArray = $this->getArray();
        print_r($tmpArray);
        echo "<br>\n";
        $tmpArray = 'Goodbye World';
        print_r($tmpArray);
        echo "<br>\n";
        print_r($this->array);
    }

}

$test = new test;
$test->add();
```

To sum it up, add() and __construct() are for testing.  I am trying to add to `$this->array` with add().  However when I specify `$tmpArray = 'Goodbye World'` the referenced array `$this->array['key1']['key2']` is still Hello World.

Could someone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Err.. what does your class achieve? I am confused..

Comment: This is mostly a testing class.  The most important part is getArray() which references the 'key2' of `$this->array` since key2 is the last specified in `$this->keys`.  $tmpArray is equal to Hello World from the reference before I set it to Goodbye World.  But I am trying to get `$this->array['key1']['key2']` to equal Goodbye World too from the reference.

Comment: Where does `$tags` exist in the class variables, where does `$values` exist in the class variables, you must be getting errors? I can't see any variable declarations inside `test`.

Comment: My fault, that was a bad copy.  It should have been keys, and values should have been array.  It has been fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to return references in PHP, you need to use `&` twice, once in the definition and once more in assignment. You're missing the one in assignment:

```
$tmpArray = &$this->getArray();
```

See [PHP: Returning References](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) for details and please don't ask why as I'm incapable of generating rationale for PHP behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I had tried that but apparently not, but it does indeed work.